# Gmail username and password authentication

Tags: java, android, gmail-api, google-authentication

In my application i have to check user have enter correct gmail password. Is any way to authenticate gmail password in android or Third patty API which authenticate google username and password.

Comment: `Is any way to authenticate gmail password in android or Third party API which authenticate google username and password.` AFAIK NO

Comment: I found an application which received used password and authenticate  , how they done authentication is any other way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Did you try OAuth. Its the standard for using the logged in Email

Comment: it not asked for user password,my requirement is authenticate with password